# Converting multiple CSVs into shapefile using Python for loops

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, arcgis-10.5, error-000725

I have hundreds of CSV files with the naming convention similar to:

```
prcp_025_01_01.csv
prcp_025_05_01.csv
prcp_025_08_01.csv
prcp_050_01_01.csv
prcp_050_05_01.csv
prcp_050_08_01.csv
prcp_025_01_15.csv
prcp_025_05_15.csv
prcp_025_08_15.csv
```

I was wanting to create a shapefile for each CSV like so:

```
prcp_025_01_01.shp
prcp_025_05_01.shp
prcp_025_08_01.shp
prcp_050_01_01.shp
prcp_050_05_01.shp
prcp_050_08_01.shp
prcp_025_01_15.shp
prcp_025_05_15.shp
prcp_025_08_15.shp
```

When running the following code, it will create the first shapefile of
prcp_025_01_01.shp
But then error out with

> ERROR 000725: Layer Name or Table View: Dataset prcp_dly_layer already
> exists. Failed to execute (MakeXYEventLayer).

Im running 10.5.1
Below is my script. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

```
import arcpy
import os
arcpy.env.workspace=r"C:\path"
shps=arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
SR=arcpy.SpatialReference(4269) #WGS 1984

for shp in shps:
    print arcpy.Describe(shp).spatialReference.name

elem = ["025", "050", "100", "400"]
month = ["01", "05", "08", "12"]
day = ["01", "15", "31"]
for element in elem:
    for mon in month:
        for dy in day:
                in_table=r"C:\path\csv_files/prcp_" + element + "_" + mon + "_" + dy + ".csv"
                prcp_dly_layer=arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(in_table, "LON", "LAT", "prcp_dly_layer", SR)
                
                fc=arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(prcp_dly_layer, r"C:\path\prcp/" + "prcp_" + element + "_" + mon + "_" + dy + "_" + '.shp')

print(arcpy.GetCount_management(prcp_dly_layer))
```

Comment: Just like the message says, the "prcp_dly_layer" layer exists. You either need to sequence it or delete the layer before creating it a second time.

Answer (score 1):

Based on what you've stated you want as output I would try this simpler code instead. Note that the output location for the shapefiles is currently set as the folder containing the CSVs `outPath = arcpy.env.workspace`, so you may want to change this.

```py
#Import modules
import arcpy
import os

#Set workspace
arcpy.env.workspace = r"C:\path"

#Create list of all csvs in folder
inputFiles = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv")

#Variable
outPath = arcpy.env.workspace

#Loop through each csv
for file in inputFiles:
    #Set the output name to be the same as the input
    outLayer = file
    #Create the temporary XY layer
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(file, "LON", "LAT", outLayer)
    
    #Make the layer a permanent shapefile
    arcpy.FeatureClassToFeatureClass_conversion(outLayer, outPath, outLayer)
```

Comment: Thanks for the simpler code, however its not creating anything for me. Id really like to have this working for me as I have hundreds of csv's with random names that need to be created into shapefiles. I notice it does not declare a projection (WGS 1984) or have a print statement at the end. However I do not think those are the issues here.

Comment: You say it's not creating anything, at what stage - creating XY layer or shapefile? Are you getting any errors?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to figure it out. Below is a snippet of my final code.

```
`SR=arcpy.SpatialReference(4269) #WGS 1984
 inputFiles = arcpy.ListFiles("*.csv")
 outPath = arcpy.env.workspace
 for csvfile in inputFiles:
    print csvfile
    #Set the output name to be the same as the input
    outLayer = "CSVEventLayer"
    arcpy.MakeXYEventLayer_management(csvfile,"LON","LAT",outLayer,SR)
    shpfile = os.path.splitext(csvfile)[0].replace('csv','')
    arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(outLayer,shpfile)
    arcpy.Delete_management(outLayer)`
```